# Can't derive transfer function of RC filter with load

Tags: filter, low-pass, books

I am trying to go along with an example on a simple RC filter with load in a book called Practical electronics for inventors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOi4Z8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Although I have a general idea on how to calculate frequency response, I cannot understand how they simplified the expression $$ H = \frac{\frac{1}{jwC}\left| \right|R_{load}}{R+[\frac{1}{jwC}\left| \right|R_{load}]}$$ into $$H = \frac{R\acute{}}{1+j(wR\acute{}C)}$$ where \$R\acute{}=R\left| \right|R_{load}\$.

I am not able to derive the above expression from the first one, I only ended up with \$H\:=\:\frac{1}{1+\frac{R}{R_{load}}+jwCR}\$

Is there any secret trick to do so, or is the book wrong? This left me very confused.

Here is a snapshot from that particular page: [image: There expression don't seem to add up]

Comment: Look at the circuit when \$s=0\$ and write the gain \$H_0\$ in this mode. Then, short the input source and temporarily disconnect the cap. then "look" through its terminals: what resistance \$R\$ do you see? Multiply \$R\$ by \$C\$ and you have the time constant \$\tau\$ of the circuit. The transfer function is therefore: \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1}{1+s\tau}\$. It can also be rewritten, \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$ with \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{\tau}\$. Done, without a single line of algebra.

Comment: Is it correct to say that transfer function of loaded filter is the same as with unloaded filter, just the R is different, in this case \$ R\left|  \right|R_{load} \$ ?

Comment: Oui, it is correct but the gain is also different as the load resistance is present and forms a divider.

Comment: I've plotted both transfer functions in Matlab, and as I raised \$R_{load}\$ to infinity, the graph of loaded filter was practically identical with the "unloaded" graph. Thank you for clearing things out for me.

Comment: If you want to learn how to determine transfer functions in a swift and effective way, check out my [APEC 2016](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) seminar on the subject of fast analytical circuits techniques (FACTs).

Answer (score 0):

I've found out there really is a mistake in the book, and the equation should be \$H = \frac{\frac{R\acute{}}{R}}{1+j(\omega R\acute{}C)}\$, the \$ \frac{1}{R}\$ term was missing.
Still a rather confusing form, but it's correct.

For anyone else who's reading the book: there is another mistake right below, where \$\omega = \frac{1}{R\acute{}C}\$ is actually the angular cutoff frequency \$\omega_{c}\$.